# Loop through nodes to list child nodes using XPathExpression java

Tags: xpath

I am new to XPath. Please help me to get category values for each report using XPathExpression in java.

```
<reports>
<report>
<allocation>
<Category>
    <c_name>Category 1</c_name>
    <c_value>5588.79776</c_value>
    <c_percent>17.84</c_percent>
    <fund_details />
</Category>
<Category>
    <c_name>Category 2</c_name>
    <c_value>7362.15208</c_value>
    <c_percent>23.50</c_percent>
    <fund_details>
        <fund>
            <f_value>3511.66</f_value>
        </fund>
    </fund_details>
</Category>
</allocation>
</report>
<report>
<allocation>
<Category>
    <c_name>Category 1</c_name>
    <c_value>12</c_value>
    <c_percent>16</c_percent>
    <fund_details />
</Category>
<Category>
    <c_name>Category 2</c_name>
    <c_value>74</c_value>
    <c_percent>02</c_percent>
</Category>
</allocation>
</report>
</reports>
```

**expected output:**
List of c_name,c_value,c_percent from category node for each report node.

Comment: report/allocation//Category

Answer (score 0):

You can download an xpath plug in on your browser. This way you only have to right click the element you want to get and view its xpath . I don't know which browser you usually use but I use firefox's firebug plugin which is ideal. I just inspect using it right click the element and copy its xpath to my code;